# Get data from URL json in R

Tags: json, r

I'm using R and I would like to get JSON information from url and I have around 5000 user agent to sent to this API (http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/api.php)

I use this code to create the url and concatenate the user-agent:

```
url_1<-paste(" \"http://www.useragentstring.com/?uas=",uaelenchi[11,1],"&getJSON=all\"",sep = '');
json_data2<-fromJSON(readLines(cat(url_1)))
```

But I receive this error:

```
Error in readLines(cat(url_1)) : 'con' is not a connection
```

Any suggestions would be really appreciated! Thanks

Comment: You've got extra quotes and space ( \") you need to get rid of. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `readLines` and `cat`, either; just make a single string (or a longer vector to `lapply`) with `paste0`. Also, `httr` is useful if you want to take this process to the next level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `rjson::fromJSON(file = paste(your_url))`. If you make a reproducible example, I could check if it is working in your case.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)

uas <- c("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0", 
"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0", 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0", 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.6 Safari/537.11", 
"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; OpenBSD amd64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0", 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0", 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.6 Safari/537.11", 
"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; OpenBSD amd64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0", 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20120405 Firefox/14.0a1", 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/7046A194A", 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1944.0 Safari/537.36", 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20120405 Firefox/14.0a1", 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/7046A194A", 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1944.0 Safari/537.36")

parse_uas <- function(uas) {
  res <- GET("http://www.useragentstring.com/", query=list(uas=uas, getJSON="all"))
  stop_for_status(res)
  content(res, as="text", encoding="UTF-8") %>% 
    fromJSON(res, flatten=TRUE) %>% 
    as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}

map_df(uas, parse_uas)
```

To save API calls you should add a caching layer to the `parse_uas()` function, which could be done pretty easily with the `memoise` package:

```
library(memoise)

.parse_uas <- function(uas) {
  res <- GET("http://www.useragentstring.com/", query=list(uas=uas, getJSON="all"))
  stop_for_status(res)
  content(res, as="text", encoding="UTF-8") %>% 
    fromJSON(res, flatten=TRUE) %>% 
    as.data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}

parse_uas <- memoise(.parse_uas)
```

Also, if you're on Linux, you can also try [this package](https://ironholds.org/blog/user-agent-parsing-in-r/) (it doesn't compile well on macOS and not at all on Windows IIRC) which will do all the processing locally.